# Underline Overflow™ in links under answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks

It looks like the CSS for links in the UI has recently changed, and most of the links are now always underlined:

[image]

This is a little heavy IMHO, and is not consistent with other links on the page (e.g. user cards under questions).

It happens for me on Chromium 77.0.3865.120.

Is this a bug? Can it be fixed?

[image]

Please?

Comment: I get this too on Firefox and Chrome (only on answers - not questions) - was writing the same question.

Comment: Yep, I'm on Chrome 79 and I just noticed this within the last few minutes. I happened to have a tab open where the answer links looked fine, refreshed it, and now they're underlined just like in the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, my main concern is that it was taking up too much space, making it difficult to write comments. Feel free to replace it with a smaller version. Also, for the meme I added, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/316142?r=SearchResults&s=1|48.2839#316142.

Comment: Ha. Yeah, that's not intentional. We'll fix it up.

Comment: Repro'ed here as well on both Firefox and Edge, logged in and logged out, only answers as well

Comment: MSO version: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392798/why-have-some-hyperlinks-started-being-underlined-and-others-not

Comment: @AdamLear [Banners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41006/282094), Q, A, and C [on some sites](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63089/is-a-notch-filter-for-50-hz-without-delay-possible#comment127774_63089) - FF Android, desktop view. Not answers only.

Comment: btw "fix up" != "fix"

Comment: @AdamLear I do like the link underlines on comments. You should keep those.

Comment: The change is the addition of the selector `.answercell a:not(.post-tag):not(.badge-tag)` to the CSS rule in primary.css which used to be `.post-text a:not(.post-tag):not(.badge-tag), .comment-copy a, .wmd-preview a:not(.post-tag):not(.badge-tag) { text-decoration:underline }`

Comment: I'm assuming this was another bug in the work to refactor all the sites CSS now that various legacy browsers are no longer officially being supported.

Comment: Same happens to links inside of posts. [Not happening in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53173094#53173094) on mobile or desktop. The glitch in desktop does not happen on the mobile site

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ever look at a line of CSS and think "that seems legit"? I should really stop doing that.

The fix is live in production. Thanks for the report!